# Sound with CAPS LOCK key

Tags: windows-7, windows, system-sounds

I run Windows 7 with a Microsoft Ergo 4000 keyboard. Please, how do I get the system to make a noise when I press the CAPS LOCK key.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 can be set to beep when the CapsLock, NumLock or ScrollLock keys are pressed.

To do this search for **Ease of Access Center** (and/or access it via the Control Panel), then in the EAC click **Make the keyboard easier to use**, and then turn on *Toggle Keys*.

[image: Toogle Keys Setting]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable *Toggle Keys* which can be done by holding the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key for 5 seconds, and click yes when the dialog box pops up.